# install_version("mvpart", "1.6-2") error

Tags: r

i'm having problems installing mvpart package in the newest version of R studio. The error comes always when I try to run using the command using devtools. Any tips how to solve this problem? thanks

> install_version("mvpart", "1.6-2")
>   Downloading package from url: https://cran.rstudio.com//src/contrib/Archive/mvpart/mvpart_1.6-2.tar.gz
>   Installing mvpart
>   '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ  \
>     --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
>     '/private/var/folders/0f/f2mkw2nn7gs01r7b33cw_x4r0000gn/T/Rtmpj91VCE/devtools6bda395f9bcf/mvpart'  \
>     --library='/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library'  \
>     --install-tests

- installing *source* package ‘mvpart’ ...
  ** package ‘mvpart’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** libs
  xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mvpart’
- removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/mvpart’
  Installation failed: Command failed (1)

Comment: This may help https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/254381/161686

Comment: Thank you so much @MartinSchmelzer! It was really helpful and fixed my problem!